# Oracle 11g on Mac OS X

Tags: oracle, macos, oracle11g

I need to install Oracle Database on Mac OS X. I recently developped a NodeJS application using MySQL and now, I need this one to be compatible with Oracle, this is why I need Oracle Database on my Mac OS X, I will developped the Oracle version of the application...

What's the best way to install Oracle on Mac OS X?

I tried to install Oracle using this page : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/intel-macsoft-096467.html

Installed package : `Version 11.2.0.4.0 (32-bit) Instant Client Package - Basic: All files required to run OCI, OCCI, and JDBC-OCI applications`

But it seem's not working because on my terminal I'm not able to execute `sqlplus`...

And is there a client interface for Oracle?

Anthony

Comment: The link you provide is just for the client software. You'd need to install the full database product, and as far as I'm aware Oracle does not provide a version of the database product which runs on Mac OSX. [11g Express Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html) is only available on   Windows and Linux, and [the full product](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html) only expands that to Solaris, HP-UX, AIX, and zLinux. Best of luck.

Comment: Ok so, I need to install the full database product on a linux virtual machine? What's the best way? Virtualbox?

Comment: I'm not familiar with installing Oracle, just using it.

Answer (score 7):

There is no Oracle database server available on current macosx. The last Oracle version was 10.2.0.4, even a quick and incomplete 10.2.0.5 but that was years ago.
Now we do have clients. See [installation instructions for macosX](http://ronr.blogspot.nl/2014/10/how-to-install-oracle-instant-client-on.html)

Currently there is also a java client that works pretty well but still is under development. De EA of sqlcl can be found here [Oracle SQL Developer 4.1 EA2 (4.1.0.18.37)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev-41ea-2372780.html), last update was yesterday.

If you really need an Oracle server, go for VirtualBox and create a Linux image for it to run Oracle-12 in. VirtualBox can be found here https://www.virtualbox.org/. For now, stay with OEL-6, that you can find here [just pick V52218-01](https://edelivery.oracle.com/EPD/Download/get_form?egroup_aru_number=18197008)

Answer (score 2):

These days it's very easy to spin up a complete Oracle server in Docker for Mac.

One image I found to be working very well is https://hub.docker.com/r/sath89/oracle-12c/

Comment: can one connect to the oracle db from outside docker via a jdbc driver?

Comment: exactly, thats the purpose of the docker containers. The Oracle ports from inside docker are mapped to local ports

Answer (score 0):

for just compatibility issue with Oracle you could using H2 database with oracle mode
of course it does not have extended features but for testing is very good

good luck