# Oracle database 11g on mac os x

Tags: oracle11g

What would be the best practice to install the 11g on OS X 10.10 machine for dev purpose? The info online says to use virtualbox and Oracle linux, is there a way to run it natively on MAC?

Comment: You can't really, at least not in any kind of a supported way, and possibly not at all; there has been no native server since 10gR2. VirtualBox is probably your best bet; see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13323391/266304), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32827872/266304), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29649699/266304) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33526064/266304) among others.

Comment: Oracle stopped supporting Mac OS natively a while ago.  I doubt you'll be able to do anything without some sort of VM.

Comment: Is there any good tutorial about how to setup Oracle DB 11g R2 on openSuse linux VM? Meanwhile having some troubles to find something useful when of the posts are talking about lack of support for the Suse 12

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use that distro, rather than [a pre-built VM image](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html) on OEL (which is essentially RedHat)? If you want to learn about DB installation and DBA tasks then fair enough; but if you want to do development the pre-built stuff saves a lot of effort and hassle.

Comment: Alex, thanks for the push in the right direction, that's the approach I'm planning to explore starting Tomorrow. BTW I couldn't find any .iso images of OEL 6.x and 11g R2.